# Wildcad selector with ignoring similar matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So i want to hide all elements and use

```
$('[id^=option_]').hide();
```

And that works fine, however it is hiding things i dont want it to hide. I have dynamically generated ids such as

option_1
option_1_form
option_2
option_2_form

So as you can see it will also hide the forms. So i was wondering if there was a way to either filter _form out or use a regular expression of some sort for the selector

```
('[id^=option_][id$=/[^0-9 ]+/]')
```

Not that the example would work, but an example of what i mean! This would force the _form to be excluded since it would have to end in a numeric value. If you know of a better way, i am all for it too. I am no jQuery wiz.

Comment: Your proposed solution looks for something ending with a number but your description seems to imply that you want to just not include `_form`.  If you do in fact only want to exclude things with `_form` that is easier and does not require regex.

Comment: I am looking for either or, as i am not sure which is easier/better/more efficient with jQuery. Kinda why i left it open for interpretation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to exclude `forms`

```
$('[id^=option_]:not(form)').hide();
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks. However do you know if "not" would be better usage than "filter"? Seems filter would have to run through the dom a second time to remove anything it doesn't want where as not can do it while in the dom the first time? Either way i will accept this because it does work.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to exclude anything containing `_form` in the `id`:

```
$('[id^=option_]:not([id|=_form])').hide();
```

`|=` is for "contains".

Comment: And the difference in yours and the one above? As his works without the id|= as well. Still learning these little tricks.

Comment: @AustinBest The other answer excludes `<form>` elements which is very different than excluding an element with an `id` that contains the string `_form`.

Comment: So in short, yours is a more specific way of the one above?

Comment: It's two different things.  If you want to exclude `<form>` elements then the other answer is better.  If you can have elements which are not `<form>` that can have `_form` in their `id` that you also want to exclude, this will work.  For instance, `<span id="option_form_span">` would be excluded with my code and included with the other.

Comment: Ha, i get what you are saying now. TY